# Merge two data frames in R according to ID-variable

Tags: r, merge

I am trying to merge two data frames in R according to ID-variable , since in the first data frame the ID-variable is a factor and in the second data frame the ID-variable is a numeric vector

```
datC <- data.frame("ID" = c("001","010","100","110"), "X" = rnorm(4))
datD <- data.frame("ID" = c(001,010,100,110,210), "Y" = rpois(5,3))
merge(datC,datD,by="ID")

ID           X  Y
100  0.03284493 2
110 -0.41690986 3
```

As we see the 001,010 are missing , and it is clear for me why they are missing 
and how I can solve this

```
datC$ID <- as.numeric(as.character(datC$ID))
merge(datC,datD,by="ID")
```

I have tried to find another solution by let R avoid TO treat a vector of character as a factor

```
datC <- data.frame("ID" = c("001","010","100","110"), "X" = rnorm(4),stringsAsFactors = F)
datD <- data.frame("ID" = c(001,010,100,110,210), "Y" = rpois(5,3))
```

When I merged these two data frames according to the ID-variable , I expected that I will get null results , since we have a character vs numeric vectors but in fact R gave me the same results as the ID-Variable in the first data frame is a factor .

```
merge(datC,datD,by="ID")

ID          X  Y
100 -0.2797956 4
110 -1.0397791 4
```

So can someone explain me why my expectation was false !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you merge two columns, they are coerced to a common `class`:

> Factors, raw vectors and lists are converted to character vectors, and then `x` and `table` are coerced to a common type (the later of the two types in R's ordering, logical < integer < numeric < complex < character) before matching.
>
> (from the `?match` help page, linked from `?merge`)

So your `numeric` column becomes `character`, as does your `factor`:

```
as.character(c(001,010,100,110,210))
# [1] "1"   "10"  "100" "110" "210"
```

This explains the result seen in the OP. This sort of coercion is common throughout R.

---

*Comment.* For ID columns, I always use `character`; it's a lot less hassle than the alternatives. `sprintf` is handy for adding leading zeros, ensuring all IDs are the same character-length:

```
sprintf("%03d", c(001,010,100,110,210))
# [1] "001" "010" "100" "110" "210"
```

Comment: Thanks , I had to see how the factor became nummeric `as.numeric(as.character(datC$ID))`